# Total of Sub Total

Tags: ssrs-tablix

I want to calculate the Sum of sub total.
In the sub total I Have the average of a field from the data Base.
the expression that I use is

```
=Sum(AVG(Fields!ON_HAND_START.Value))
```

But does not show the right value.

In the sample the Total should be **390 **not 154. [SSRS Report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aoqn.png)